# What to do with tags low on questions and followers for a long time?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

What should I do with the tag which is low on questions, without any followers and is quite old (lets say more than a year old)?

I think good example here can be [fast-app-switching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fast-app-switching) - the first post appeared somewhere in 2011, now there are 24 questions, no followers, and it's hard (at least for me) to describe what that tag should handle. Ok, Windows Phone has something like Fast App Resume, but it only stands for *Silverlight*, there are by a chance one or two questions from iOS, but separate tag for this?

It's quite easy for me to handle such situation, there are only 24 questions, but should I handle this myself or raise the problem on meta with burninate request?

Also what would happen to a tag when it becomes empty - no questions and followers?

Comment: Unused tags are pruned daily. Single-use-tags stay around about a month (I think) until they get trashed too. Followers don't factor into that at all.

Comment: @Deduplicator Daily - quite fast, on the other hand with so many tags created every day, it seems to be reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Now that we have a [better and standardized process for burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/4099593), we can follow the guidance given there:

> If you have authoritative knowledge of all technologies relevant to the tag, have conferred with at least one other [trusted community member](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), and are dealing with a tag that has a small number of questions (< 50), then you can go ahead and remove it yourself or with a little ad hoc help.

However, [do note that all the burnination requests must go through the meta route](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356963/tag-removals-must-be-discussed-and-documented-on-meta). Therefore to answer your question:

> It's quite easy for me to handle such situation, there are only 24 questions, but should I handle this myself or raise the problem on meta with burninate request?

You need to raise a [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) on meta, complete with your reasoning on how the [tag fails the 4 criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191),  and then wait for the community to decide. Once you get the go from the community, (which would take perhaps a day or two), you can start the burnination, and seek the help of others who have agreed with you on the meta post.