# Tag removals must be discussed and documented on Meta

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, burninate-system, announcement

Recently I was notified that a user, who has since been suspended, went on a mass-edit spree to remove tags that they believed were not needed on the site. Many of these tags had, and still have, thousands of questions associated with them. Each tag also has followers to it, the top one having 26k followers.

Now, this isn't a question of whether or not these were valid tags that should remain on the site. They very well could be terrible tags that potentially should be removed altogether. The problem is one user decided to single-handedly edit out the tags without input or discussion from the people who use those tags, and without leaving documentation that would allow them to understand what happened or why.

We have a [well-documented process in place to remove tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination), and we even have a [site to have the discussion on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Following this process allows the community to be involved, and decide if a tag should be removed and why. Documenting the process of removing a tag on meta makes the removal visible to everyone, allowing others to help or to raise an objection.  We do not want this to be done in the shadows where significant damage could be done by a single user.

The [burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) is in place to allow users who follow a tag or contribute to it to have the chance to weigh in on the validity of the tag, *prior* to its removal. If a tag is removed without discussion or feedback, then the workflow of those who depend on the tag (whether for identifying questions that interest them or ignoring questions that do not) is potentially impacted by it.

This is just a friendly reminder that we have a process to do this and that it should be followed... The incident that prompted this resulted in our team spending the morning restoring tags to over 12 thousand questions, a waste of time both for us and for the editor who removed them.

Now back to your regularly scheduled [Friday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfVsfOSbJY0).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.  [This'll keep Cody's fine crystalware](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335175/can-we-clean-up-the-macbook-and-macbookpro-tags/356210#comment511552_356210) ([and mine, for that matter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356898/do-we-support-production-support#comment516346_356898)) from shattering for a while.

Comment: The thing is: that the process is most of the time booring... it's so boring that people disagree with a tag burnination simply because they consider _the process itself_ to be of little use and a drag. Well, guess what, the process is indeed of little use, it's a drag, but the effects are worthwhile. Also, your guidance doesn't even consider clear cut cases, like the good old typo tag.

Comment: @Braiam:  It does cover it.  Talk to someone who's an expert on the topic matter, and if there's less than 50 questions in the tag, it's fine to take care of between the handful of you.  For larger tags is where it starts to get unwieldy.

Comment: @Makoto in the 5 paragraph long post that is [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356963/792066), doesn't mention exceptions of any kind. It says very explicitly in the title: that all tag removals should be discussed, and the body doesn't phantom any exception to this.

Comment: Ah, and before you start talking about [this other post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/792066), it doesn't either.

Comment: The [bug] tag would not be inappropriate.  Almost anything is rate limited at the site.  Tag removal is not.  By far the simplest and direct way to slow them down.

Comment: @Braiam:  "If you have authoritative knowledge of technologies relevant to the tag, have conferred with at least one other trusted community member, and are dealing with a tag that has a small number of questions (< 50), then you can go ahead and remove it yourself or with a little ad hoc help."  I admit I learned this relatively recently myself...but it *is* there.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that 12,000 tag edits is **a lot of tag edits.**

Comment: Vast majority of tag removals discussed here on meta **are** a pointless waste of time, @braiam. Vast majority of worthwhile tag removals are removing newly-created tags with 1 question. The former don't become less a waste when done sloppy.

Comment: @Compass:  That's 12,000 questions which could've been deleted (if necessary), edited into shape (if necessary), or closed (if necessary).  It's a lot and it's unfortunate that couldn't have happened.

Comment: Which is why I get so tired of all these "rules" that has to be followed, except when I like some more important ones to be followed. It's like everything is created to introduce as much bureaucracy without any clear advantage over simply following good old anarchy. It doesn't make the process more efficient nor effective. There's no guarantee of experts (on the working of tags, not the topic these represent) being able to weight in these issues. I've said this before, tags are the most powerful tool that SE has, yet all that power is mostly wasted.

Comment: @Braiam I'm afraid I don't follow what you mean by "good old anarchy", specifically the combination of "good" and "anarchy".

Comment: @TylerH anarchy is the lack of "order", good because it's better than what we have now.

Comment: Is there a threshold for the number of questions a tag should have before needing to discuss it on meta? Makoto mentioned 50. Is that the agreed upon number?

Comment: @Suragch: That was what was written, although I did read comments suggesting half that. You should bring it up on Meta if you're *not* a subject matter expert and enlist their help, even if it's only 20 questions, to avoid poor edits.

Comment: @Braiam I very much doubt that anarchy is a better system. There often is disagreement when submitting a burninate request, and just allowing people who want to destroy tags to freely destroy them, would probably spark Edit War 3, where the only defense against an improper burninate would be to reverse all the edits. And with robotic warfare, that would end badly for the site. Yes, we do have [quite the backlog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356820/why-do-some-burninate-request-with-over-20-votes-not-get-featured) and it's slow and requires work. But it surely is better than nothing

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth yet, we had that for ~8 years and we were not any different than what we are today. In fact, we were better, because this post didn't even happen and SE was more willing to use their tools to remove tags from the system.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to block tag removal for tags with more than, say, 10 or 20 questions, unless there has been a discussion? Or even let them be removed by mods only? I don't know what volume we're talking about here..

Comment: @GolezTrol: The trouble is that any given edit removes one occurrence of the tag.  Retagging a question — removing or adding tags — is one of those things that must be doable without friction.  People continually make mistakes.  What you're suggesting wouldn't work at the 'single edit level', therefore (not being able to remove a [tag:c] tag from a [tag:c++] question or vice versa without going through MSO would be intolerable — and both those tags have way more than 20 questions).  So, that probably wasn't what you meant. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ Given that you probably had in mind something like "if a single user removes the tag from more than N questions in a row where the tag has more than M other questions, then stop them".  That becomes unwieldy to process in the SO code base (to be polite about it).  In short, I don't think your suggestion actually works on SO.  Worth suggesting, perhaps, but it seems impracticable to me.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Point taken, I think my assumption about the tag process was incorrect.

Comment: @Makoto not sure why  you link to comment responding to me, I have never removed tags if I don't think the question is on-topic while improving the whole Q/A, I have participated actively in many tag burnation, my comment was simply related to few question (11), clear cut example of bad tag, lets clean up no need for the whole burnation process,

Comment: The problem with these burnation is that lots of people like to discuss it on meta but very few then actively partecipate (did you all review entry, research, guidelines, godaddy, apple). My suggestion to all is stop posting burnation request  and instead start helping out to clean up the request we already have.

Comment: @PetterFriberg:  I was only highlighting an "Eeek" moment from me.  Nothing personal.

Comment: "We do not want this to be done in the shadows where significant damage could be done by a single user." sounds like something that should be rate limited instead of finding out about it after the fact...

Comment: *Which tag can I burrrrrrrrrn*

Comment: @Jamal: When you have less that 2000 reputation, you can't usefully burn a tag because your edits have to be reviewed, which makes more work rather than helping clean up the site.  When you have enough reputation to make changes without needing other people to review them, then you can look to help with burnination — carefully.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I was actually trying to make it sound like one of the lines in the song that was linked to at the very end, hence the italics. :)

Comment: What is this about. I see this kind of tag clean-ups often. I feel I goed to reject them, but I don't know what a good reason would be. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17438026

Comment: How many questions must be using the tag and how many followers must it have, in order to motivate the formal procedure? If I see one crappy tag with 0 followers and just a handful of questions using it, I can just edit them and be done with it in a few minutes. We shouldn't create too much bureaucracy for simple tasks.

Comment: Please don't suspend him for a long time for that. Even 1 day is enough for that, getting a year for that is a **huge** punishment, while his good faith was obvious (i.e. he surely didn't want to destruct content, he wanted to clean something up).

Comment: @Lundin In my opinion, all tag removals should be approved through community consensus before actioning. There are many misconceptions about when tags should be removed and when they should be left alone. The community needs to be a part of the decision, not just one person.

Comment: I feel like downvoting, just because you linked to that Friday video :-(

Comment: @joshmcode I guess I could have [used this instead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ).

Comment: Someone removed tags from 12 *thousand* questions in a single day? I haven't even done 12,000 edits *total*.

Comment: @EJoshuaS It was not done in a single day. It was over the course of about 2 weeks.

Comment: @bluefeet Even so... that's a lot. That's almost 1000 a day. Exactly how much time was this individual spending on that?

Comment: @EJoshuaS Too much, especially considering we rolled it all back. If they had gone through the proper channels in the first place, it would have saved a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Yeah, and I thought that voting to close 50 items in a single day was a lot. Editing 1000 posts is absurd.

Comment: Seems like a waste, especially given how tedious editing tags is - did they at least take part in Meta-approved burninations?

Comment: @EJoshuaS They was a significant lack of discussion about it which lead to this reminder.

Comment: It seems like the fact that one of the tags had 26k followers is significant evidence in and of itself that that tag should **not** have been burninated - after all, the point of having tags in the first place is to help people find posts that they're interested in, and the fact that it had so many followers indicated that it's doing that.

Comment: @EJoshuaS The fact that a tag has a given number of followers may lend to the discussion, but should never be a deciding factor in whether or not a tag should be burninated. Contrary to popular belief, the purpose of tags is not solely to help people find posts to answer. While that is one use of tags, there are many others and those uses need to be taken into account when evaluating the usefulness of a given tag.

Comment: @Lundin See [the Meta post bluefeet links to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/366904), specifically the top portion, item #1. That covers when it's acceptable to remove a tag yourself without following the formal process. I rewrote it recently to make it clearer. The idea is, like you said, to avoid cumbersome bureaucratic processes for simple tasks, so if you know what you're doing, have sanity-checked it, and are working on a small scale, then you can just fix the problem yourself. If it's too large, or you're unsure, then you need to get community input.

Comment: Not everyone visits Meta, can it be made clear **while editing** that it is not encouraged to do these mass-tag removals on your own? What if, in the future someone decides to remove tags from another 12K questions and he doesn't know about this consensus because he doesn't visit Meta?

Comment: @g00glen00b If the don't visit meta, then the person doesn't know how the site moderation works and is therefore very much unsuitable to do any form of user moderation tasks.

Comment: @Lundin ok, but those people do get the privileges to do any user moderation, regardless of them visiting Meta. Pretty sure there's a large group of people that edit based on their experience with this site, rather than what they read on Meta. That's not bad I guess, but for "bigger processes" they still have the tools (the privileges), but not the right experience (Meta knowledge), and my question is how do you prevent this from happening again for people in this category.

Comment: I put a merge request in awhile back for several tags that were just different English tenses of the same word. That garnered 3 upvotes and 2 downvotes with only one user leaving a question comment who never bothered to come back after I addressed it. Does that mean it was a worthless suggestion, or that no one else in the community was willing to spend their time on it?

Comment: @SandPiper That doesn't mean it's a worthless request, it is a sign that it might not be a critical change at this time.

Comment: @bluefeet Should it be left alone completely, then? Small site improvements are still improvements. If there is someone willing to put in the time to fix it but no one else is willing to even give it the time of day to comment yeah or nay, why not just go ahead and fix it ourselves? If no one can be bothered to comment, would they be bothered to undo all those retags?

Comment: Does responsibility stop at the user? Who is responsible for giving that ability out? Who is responsible for the system that automatically empowers people? Are there not multiple levels of accountability?

Answer (score 107):

> We do not want this to be done in the shadows where significant damage could be done by a single user.

Then please also create and run some security scripts that look for such suspicious behavior like mass tag removal. Reminding people is nice but may not persuade those who just want a tag removed without discussion. Better to be safe than sorry.

> The incident that prompted this resulted in our team spending the morning restoring tags to over 12 thousand questions, a waste of time...

Couldn't you just kind of undo all the tag changes of the user for a certain time period? Such tools, if available, might be very handy.

Comment: Yeah, I think we can avoid rate limiting tag edits or edits in general and *still* include a warning to mods that someone has just made 12k tag edits. Heck, even a warning at 500 tag edits would probably not have too many false positives.

Comment: Technically no one should be editing just the tags during burninations anyways. Questions that require just tag edits should be left to the end for the CM tool to take care of. I think more than 10 tag-only edits in a short period of time should raise an auto flag.

Comment: [This chat conversation](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/mass-tagging-tool) describes the available tools. Quotes: _I got to use a tool I've never touched before and wasn't sure actually worked_ [...] _no idea what it was originally intended for. Added 5 years ago with the comment "new route that adds a single tag to multiple questions **DANGEROUS!**"_

Comment: I like the suggestion in this post. Just like serial voting reversal, implement a serial tag-removing reversal. Make the perpetrator think they've done a good and thorough job wrecking the site, only to find their sabotage undone the next day. That will make them think twice before trying again.

Comment: I'd be more of a fan of a tag removal to have a 24(?) hour waiting period, during which it can be cancelled by moderators (or someone else?) if they feel the matter has not been adequately discussed. Perhaps involving an automated post to the effect of "Tag [X] will be deleted" for the sake of exact documentation.

Comment: @acdr That is an orthogonal suggestion; it doesn't fix someone burning 12 thousand tags at 1000/day.

Comment: @Yakk Not retroactively, no, but I imagine it might be a lot easier to hit a "deny request to remove tag" button than to edit the tags of a question. (And the same consideration for writing a script to perform those actions programmatically.) But thinking about it, you're right in that that's an orthogonal suggestion: it wouldn't prevent anyone from doing bad things to begin with.

Comment: @acdr People use the wrong tags all the time. Editing tags _is_ appropriate, and there can't be a delay for such changes. Your proposed solution would break the rest of the site.

Comment: I'm not proposing a delay on editing tags on a question. I'm proposing a delay on removing the existence of tags from the site, like the OP's tale.

Comment: @acdr: You can't trivially draw that distinction.  A tag is composed of a body of questions which have it.  Removing a tag from all of the questions *is* removing it from the site.  You can't prevent the latter without interfering with the former, unless you use some kind of rate-limiting or otherwise statistical, non-binary approach to the problem.