# Should tags for deprecated versions be removed from questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

In the Suggestes Edits review queue, I recently came across some suggestions that want to remove the [powershell-v2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-v2.0) from questions. The edit reason given was

> powershell v2 is deprecated

Here are some of the reviews:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19113107
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19102905
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19125187

Some of the questions may need some actual editing, but that is not the question here. There have been some acceptances, because the [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) was still in there or was edited in. Others were rejected, because after the edit, there was no more [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell).

I believe the [powershell-v2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-v2.0) was relevant at the time of asking the question, either because that was the current version at the time or it is the version in use.<sup>1</sup>

How should we handle those (and further) edit suggestions?

---

<sup>1</sup> Sidenote: Windows 7 has PowerShell v2.0 by default and needs to be manually upgraded in order to get a higher version.

Comment: Hopefully he'll get enough rejects to quit doing this.  You can hurry that along by posting [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356963/tag-removals-must-be-discussed-and-documented-on-meta) to one of his posts.  Nvm, I took care of it.

Comment: "Oh no, someone is using a deprecated version of PowerShell... better remove that tag. There, that'll teach 'em."

Comment: Imo deprecated versions are _especially_ relevant tags. If you're tagging [tag:powershell], people likely assume you're using a supported version. If you tag the deprecated version too, your question can both be excluded by people that don't want to see questions about that, and found easier by people who are interested in that version.