# Can we have tags for Spring 6/Spring Boot 3?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-request

With Spring 6 and Spring Boot 3, there came a lot of changes. Most notably, there is a minimum requirement on Java 17 and it uses Jakarta EE 9 coming with a namespace change. But there were also other changes like the deprecation/removal of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Due to this (and many other changes), I think a [spring-boot-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot-3) and [spring-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-6) should exist, especially since the tags [spring-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-3), [spring-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-4), [spring5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring5) exist as well.

In fact, I already [created a [spring-boot-3] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74429592/revisions) (which got used on quite a few questions) but it was removed. The same user also removed the same tag multiple times by now  including in a [bulk of edits on the 23rd of June](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22982/brian-clozel?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=5) (edited 75 questions) which mainly seem to be about removing [spring-boot-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot-3) (I didn't look at all edits but apart from a few [spring6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring6) removals, I only found cases where they removed [spring-boot-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot-3) there).

While this user does have authoritative knowledge about this tag, these tags have been created multiple times and I'm pretty certain there have been >50 questions that have been retagged which does not allow a [shortened burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/10871900) as far as I am concerned so I am posting this to [document this removal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356963/tag-removals-must-be-discussed-and-documented-on-meta). I have also once tried to [contact the user on Chat.SO](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/250930/2023/1/7) but I weren't able to reach them and hope this post reaches them in some way.

Should we create [spring-boot-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot-3) and [spring-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-6) tags or should they be blacklisted for good?

Comment: Note: the fact that there is a spring-3, spring-4 and a spring5 tag does not imply that a spring-6 tag should exist, the other possibility is that some of those tags should also disappear. IMO the spring5 tag can also be safely nuked. spring-3 and spring-4 are probably worth keeping for legacy purposes, the API did change quite a bit back in those days with many deprecations. Regardless, I don't think you will get a definitive answer here. This is a typical topic with a fence in between. Take your pick which side of the fence you're on.

Comment: @Gimby - seems like meta is the correct place to reach some consensus rather than people unilaterally creating the tag and removing it with no discussion between the two

Comment: @Gimby Yes, the tag has been created and removed multiple times already so I thought we should have a question on MSO about this. I added the existence of other Spring related version tags as I thought this could be relevant. Furthermore, a lot of these questions are specific to Spring Boot 3/Spring 6.

Comment: @MartinSmith On whether specific tags need to be burned, yes. But on topics such as "do we need version tags" - good luck.

Comment: I created this question in order to put an end to the creation/removal of this tag. Users reasonably create this tag (as there are many differences between Spring Boot 2.*/3.*) and their question is specific to Spring Boot 3, quite a few users use the newly created tag, the tag is removed and it repeats. I see the options to either blacklist the tag or create it and ask the user in question to stop removing it (if this is decided here on MSE) or making the tags a synonym of `spring-boot`/`spring`

Comment: Considering Java 17 is now a requirement (for 3), then I vote that the tag stays up. That's going to be a hard hill to climb for some people.

Comment: Due to that and the switch to Jakarta EE 9 with the change from the `javax` to the `jakarta` root package name, many dependencies need to be changed as well.

Comment: Also, it is noteworthy that it can be important information whether someone is using Spring Boot 3/Spring 6 or Spring Boot 2/Spring 5.

Comment: I want to mention that we [already have a spring-boot-3 tag again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76730158/suffix-content-negotiation-in-spring-boot-3). Please don't just remove it until consensus is reached... I don't think we want any more creations/removals of that tag until then.

Comment: I haven't yet heard any arguments of how the removal of the spring-boot-3 tag makes the site better in any way. All a lack of it does is the need to add it to the question text or the first question in the comments being "what version of Spring Boot are you on" for many version-specific questions. And it makes it harder for users in the process of switching from 2 to 3 to find relevant answers.

Comment: @daniu you often use tags to do searching? I don't, I use Google. Tags are decent for finding stuff to answer, paired with a load of other filters. Regardless, I believe this meta post kind of dances around the actual root issue. There is a person, a gold badger on top of that which increases the responsibility requirements, whom is taking it upon themselves to kind of manage Spring tags as they and they alone see fit. In this case they have a vendetta with the spring-boot-3 tag apparently. What to do? We don't have a process to state which tags to keep, only for which need to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[spring-boot-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot-3) [has been recreated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76730158/suffix-content-negotiation-in-spring-boot-3) in July.

As of writing this answer, it has reached [more than 50 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot-3?tab=Votes) and should therefore definitely [not be burninated again without going through the full burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination/324071#324071).